# AppConnect Error : AppConnect cannot be instantiated directly

Tags: ios, swift, mobileiron

I am trying to Access the MDM using `AppConnect` SDK in `swift 1.2` but it is giving following error :

> [AppConnect:Error] AppConnect cannot be instantiated directly.
>   Instead, call +initWithDelegate: and then +sharedInstance.

Code Snippet :

```
 import UIKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, AppConnectDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?        
        var appct = AppConnect()

        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.   

            // Initialize the AppConnect library
            AppConnect.initWithDelegate(self)
            self.appct = AppConnect.sharedInstance()
            self.appct.startWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

            return true
        } 
}
```

Application is crashing while accessing the Keys of MobileIron Backend Config file.

Any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing AppConnect without delegate

change

`var appct = AppConnect();`

to

`var appct : AppConnect!;`

Comment: Daniel, Now app is crashing at self.appct = AppConnect.sharedInstance() with this error : [AppConnect:Error] AppConnect is unable to start because [UIApplication sharedApplication] is not an instance of AppConnectUIApplication

Comment: change `class AppDelegate: UIResponder` to `class AppDelegate : AppConnectUIApplication`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set a new key/value in the plist:

```
Principal class AppConnectUIApplication
```

or in source mode:

```
  <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>AppConnectUIApplication</string>
```

Hope it help you