# AppConnect:Error : AppConnect is unable to start because [UIApplication sharedApplication] is not an instance of AppConnectUIApplication

Tags: ios, swift, mobileiron

I am getting an error, While accessing MDM using AppConnect SDK in swift 1.2.

Error :

> [AppConnect:Error] AppConnect is unable to start because
>   [UIApplication sharedApplication] is not an instance of
>   AppConnectUIApplication.

Code Snippet :

```
import UIKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, AppConnectDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?        
        var appct : AppConnect!;

        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.   

            // Initialize the AppConnect library
            AppConnect.initWithDelegate(self)
            self.appct = AppConnect.sharedInstance()
            self.appct.startWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

            return true
        } 
}
```

Application is crashing at `self.appct = AppConnect.sharedInstance()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppConnect Error : AppConnect cannot be instantiated directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024457/appconnect-error-appconnect-cannot-be-instantiated-directly)

Answer (score 2):

Comment out `@UIApplicationMain` and change your main.swift file to the following:

```
import Foundation

UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, "AppConnectUIApplication", NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

For more information, follow the setup instructions in the Documentation folder of the SDK source. (You have to make sure you follow the instructions of the document that matches the SDK that you are using since MI changes things frequently.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set a new key/value in the plist:

```
Principal class AppConnectUIApplication
```

or in source mode:

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>AppConnectUIApplication</string>
```

Hope it help you